# Modeling stylised fur

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

[image]

How can i make something similar to the left object? Mid Poly stylised fur all around the right object.

I managed to do it with particle system , also curves and in sculpt but none of them gave the results i hoped for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could paint a black and white dot texture (or any shape of texture) in *Sculpt Mode* with the *Stencil* in order to create peaks on your torus:

[image]

If they are not sharp enough, choose the *Mesh Filter > Enhance Details*:

[image]

If the peaks need to be a bit tilted, select an inner ring, enable the *Proportional Editing* option and rotate on Z:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A more low poly option is, to use checker deselct.
[image]
Select an edge loop and then use checker deselect. You get a selection of every other vertex of the loop. You can then use rotate & scale to create spikes. This results in a very regular mesh.
[image]
Randomize verticies solves that pretty well.

I got this result in only a few minutes. WIth a bit of tweaking and proportional editing, you could easily get a very nice result. [image]